# How to pass run number from one workflow to another?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, github-pages

I have 2 workflows

First runs tests and generated allure report and second builds and deploys to github pages and sends a slack notification with the link to gh pages.

I am curious, how can I get run number of the first workflow and pass it to the second workflow as `${{github.run_number}}`?

I've tried to pass just `${{github.run_number}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the first WF to trigger the second WF and pass some inputs. At first, you need to define an input in the second workflow:

```
name: Second workflow (deploy)

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      run_number: # Exposing the input through which we can pass the value
        description: 'The run number'
        required: true

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Echo the input
        run: echo ${{ github.event.inputs.run_number }}
```

Then, you can trigger this workflow from another workflow in the following way:

```
name: First Workflow (report)

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  allure-report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # ... Allure report generation steps, etc.

      - name: Invoke the deploy WF
        uses: benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1
        with:
          workflow: deploy.yaml
          inputs: '{ "run_number": "${{ github.run_number }}" }'
```

In this example, I've used the [Workflow Dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch) GH Action to pass the current `run_number` to the `deploy.yml` WF as an input value.

To read more about workflow inputs see the [Specifying inputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#example-specifying-inputs) and [`workflow_dispatch` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch).

Comment: In the second workflow I have an event that it should wait until github pages workflow is done. How can I add the "workflow_dispatch" event alongside with "workflow_run" event within 1 workflow file? on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['pages-build-deployment']
    types:
      - completed

Comment: @oneos maybe you can use the [Wait On Check](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/wait-on-check) Action for that?